# Microsoft excel content of a cell required

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get the content of a cells if i have address of a cell, eg if i have address of a cell A4 then then excel function should give content of cell A4,B4,C4 in three different columns( i.e. three column content required)
Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions only fill one cell, the cell they are written in.

You can get the content of A4 into a cell by using `INDIRECT("A4")`, where you would of course write *your source for A4* instead `"A4"`.

If you want 'the cell to the right of A4' in the next cell, you need a more complicated function for that, for example using the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions on your "A4", add 1 to the column, and then get that value via `INDIRECT()` or `INDEX()`. Depending on where you get the A4 from there might be easier ways. I recommend you read the help for the listed functions for some examples.

Comment: `OFFSET()` is another option.

Comment: Sir, the address of the cell is stored in another cell of excel and when using row() or column() its giving row and column of that particular cell in which the address is saved. Plz hepl

Comment: you need to still use the `INDIRECT()`, for example `COLUMN(INDIRECT("A4"))`